# Passar dados de uma Activity para um Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Preciso passar a String result que esta na HomeActivity para a MapsFragment, mas não sei como fazer, sou iniciante e não entendo muito sobre o assunto.

HomeActivy

```
package mundosenai.mundosenai.com.mundosenai;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private Button botaoPostar;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
double lat;
double longi;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

String url = "";
String parametros ="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    botaoPostar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoPostarId);


    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.container, new MapsFragment(), "MapsFragment");

    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

          /*  if (GetLocalization(HomeActivity.this)) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                if (location != null) {

                    //EU PRECISO PASSAR ESSES DOIS DADOS PARA O MAPSFRAGMENT
                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    longi = location.getLongitude();
                    String.valueOf(lat);
                    String.valueOf(longi);

                    // verificação para saber se está funcionando  System.out.println("ahoasj "+lat+" aheooo" +longi);



                } else {
                    showSettingsAlert();

                }
            }*/






    botaoPostar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent abrePost = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
            String id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_user");

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                String txt = "";
                txt = id_user.toString();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("txt", txt);
                abrePost.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(abrePost);

        }
    });

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    String nome = null, mensagem = null, lat = null, longi = null;

    url = "http://192.168.0.101:80/Login/mensagem_listar.php";

    parametros = "nome=" + nome + "&mensagem=" + mensagem + "&lat=" + lat + "&longi=" + longi;

    new SolicitaDados().execute(url);

}

protected  synchronized  void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public  void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {


}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

public boolean GetLocalization(Context context) {
    int REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION = 221;
    boolean res = true;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            res = false;
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCALIZATION);

        }
    }
    return  res;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Gps não está Habilitato. Deseja configurar?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Configurar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }
    );


    alertDialog.show();
}



private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        //Parte em que converto os dados, terei que fazer isso na Fragment
        //String[] dados = result.split(",");

       // for (int i = 0; i < dados.length;i++){
            //Parte de verificação dos dados

            //if(i < dados.length - 3){
             //   System.out.println("nome:" + dados[i] + " mensagem: " + dados[i+1] + " Lat " + dados[i+2] + " Longi " + dados[i+3]);
             //   i += 3;
           // }
        }
    }
}
}
```

MapsFragment

```
package mundosenai.mundosenai.com.mundosenai;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.widget.Button;

 public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getMapAsync(this);



}




@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-27.1330088,-51.4638369);

    //map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Elvis")
            .snippet("Primeira mensagem ")
            .position(sydney));


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar um bundle

```
MapsFragment mapsFragmet = new MapsFragment();
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.put("chave","valor");
mapsFragment.setArguments(data);
```

Em MapsFragment utiliza

```
Bundle data = getArguments();
String valor = data.getString("chave");
```

Comment: Não está indo, ele não puxa as bibliotecas do put e o mapsFragment, pois estou dentro de uma private class.

Comment: @MarcosKropp o que você falou não faz sentido, você tem que criar o objeto mapsFragment da forma como o Tiago colocou e então passá-lo ao `transaction.add()`